# How to extract information from a small table in a DolphinDB database SQL query

Tags: dolphindb

I would like to do the following: 
`select * from t1 where y > (select y from t2 where x=t1.x)`. Specifically, for each row in t1, select the rows with y values higher than the y value of the row in t2 with the same x value as in the row in t1. Is there a way to do it in DolphinDB without merging t1 and t2?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict(t2.x, t2.y)
select * from t1 where y > d[x]
```

Comment: this looks very neat. Didn't know we can call a dictionary directly in a SQL query. Thanks!